# How to pass argument on pre-defined Entrypoint of an image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have to use a custom docker image, which defines `Entrypoint` like this:

```
.
.
"Entrypoint": [
    "tini",
    "-g",
    "--"
],
.
.
```

If I run `docker-compose up` without specifying any argument for this, it exited like this:

```
ml4t    | tini (tini version 0.18.0)
ml4t    | Usage: tini [OPTIONS] PROGRAM -- [ARGS] | --version
ml4t    |
ml4t    | Execute a program under the supervision of a valid init process (tini)
ml4t    |
ml4t    | Command line options:
ml4t    |
ml4t    |   --version: Show version and exit.
ml4t    |   -h: Show this help message and exit.
ml4t    |   -p SIGNAL: Trigger SIGNAL when parent dies, e.g. "-p SIGKILL".
ml4t    |   -v: Generate more verbose output. Repeat up to 3 times.
ml4t    |   -w: Print a warning when processes are getting reaped.
ml4t    |   -g: Send signals to the child's process group.
ml4t    |   -e EXIT_CODE: Remap EXIT_CODE (from 0 to 255) to 0.
ml4t    |   -l: Show license and exit.
ml4t    |
ml4t    | Environment variables:
ml4t    |
ml4t    |   TINI_VERBOSITY: Set the verbosity level (default: 1).
ml4t    |   TINI_KILL_PROCESS_GROUP: Send signals to the child's process group.
ml4t    |
ml4t exited with code 1
```

I realized that I have to pass `bash` to this `tini` command. How can I do this without creating  a new Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like your Dockerfile is missing a `CMD`.  That wouldn't usually be `bash`, but instead the actual application you'd want the container to run.

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "-g", "--"] # must be JSON-array form
CMD my_app --foreground
```

If you have [both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), they are simply combined together, and the `CMD` is passed as arguments to `ENTRYPOINT`.  This is a simplified form of a very common pattern where `CMD` contains the actual container you want to run, and `ENTRYPOINT` is a script or wrapper that does some first-time setup and then executes the `CMD` (in this case, it wraps it with a lightweight single-purpose init process).

After you make this edit to your existing Dockerfile, you can run `docker build` to rebuild the image, or `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build` if you're using Compose.  You don't need to create a new Dockerfile just to add the `CMD` (though you could if you wanted).

You can override `CMD` in a couple of ways: by including a `command:` in your `docker-compose.yml` file, or by including a command after the image name in `docker run`, or by including a command after the service name in `docker-compose run`.  It's better to put `CMD` in the Dockerfile than to put `command:` in `docker-compose.yml`, lest other users run into the same problem you have.

Answer (score -1):

use `docker-compose run` instead of `up`.

Doc: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

Comment: If I used `run`, `ports`  and `container_name` in `docker-compose.yml` are not applied...

Comment: @user3595632 you can mention ports and container name in the command along with run. `-p` for ports, `--name` to provide the name. Mentioned in the Doc